# How to edit multiple text input editor field in seperate in react js

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, typescript, object

I am working on react js and typescript. I am developing an educational app in which admin can add single mcq question and group of mcq questions. I used ckeditor for writing mcq question. when I add mcq question its mutation works fine. but in group question, it is a not working.
When I add group question, it is a combination of two mcq question. each mcq question object has its own key value pair. so in an array, there are multiple objects of the mcq question type.
Now the problem is that when I write something in one object, its value is assigned in all other object key.
suppose I am writing someting in question_text of object1, this value is also assigned in the question_text of object2, object3.... In other words, onchange function is applicable on every object within the array. I am not getting how can I fix it. Please help me out for this.

```js
const handleMcqQuestionChange = (
    value: string | number | string[],
    name: string,
    index: number
  ) => {
    if (questionType === "MultipleChoice") {
    //@ts-ignore
    questionCopy[name as keyof McqQuestionInput] = value;
    console.log("name and index", name, index)
    
    setQuestion(questionCopy);
    }
    else{
      
       //@ts-ignore
    groupQuestion[0][name as keyof McqQuestionInput] = value;
    console.log("group questions index", index)
    // const groupQuestionData =  [...mcqQuestions, questionCopy]
    // console.log("mcq questions ", mcqQuestions);
    
    setGroupQuestion(groupQuestion);
    console.log("group questions", groupQuestion)
    }
  };
  
    const handleChange = (
    value: string | number,
    name: string,
    _index: number
  ) => {
    if (questionType === "MultipleChoice") {
      console.log("index mcq", _index)
      const questionCopy: any = { ...question };
      questionCopy[name] = value;
      setQuestion(questionCopy);
    }
     else {
      console.log("index group", _index)
      const groupQuestionCopy: any = [ ...groupQuestion ];
      groupQuestionCopy[_index][name] = value;
      setGroupQuestion(groupQuestionCopy);
      console.log("group question copy", groupQuestionCopy)
    }
  };
```

```html
<Card>
            <CardContent>
              <CustomCKEditor
                label="Instructions"
                handleChange={(_event: any, content: any, _index: any) =>
                  handleInstructionsChange(
                    content && content.getData(),
                   "instruction",
                   _index
                  )
                }
                initialState={question.questionText}
                minHeight={500}
              />
            </CardContent>
          </Card>
          {groupQuestion &&
            groupQuestion.map((_questions, index) => (
              <Card>
                <CardContent>
                  <CustomCKEditor
                    label="Question"
                    handleChange={(_event: any, content: any) =>
                      handleMcqQuestionChange(
                        content && content.getData(),
                        "questionText",
                        index
                      )
                    }
                    initialState={question.questionText}
                    minHeight={500}
                  />

                  {question.options?.map((option: string, index: number) => (
                    <CustomCKEditor
                      label={`Option ${index + 1}`}
                      handleChange={(_event: any, content: any) =>
                        handleOptionChange(content && content.getData(), index)
                      }
                      initialState={option}
                      key={index}
                    />
                  ))}

                  <Typography variant="body1" style={{ marginTop: 10 }}>
                    Correct Option
                  </Typography>
                  <RadioGroup
                    row
                    name="correctOption"
                    value={groupQuestion[index].correctOption}
                    onChange={(_e, value) => {
                      // console.log(value, "value");
                      handleChange(Number(value), "correctOption", index);
                    }}
                  >
                    {question.options?.map((_option: string, index: number) => (
                      <FormControlLabel
                        value={index + 1}
                        control={<Radio />}
                        label={`options ${index + 1}`}
                      />
                    ))}
                  </RadioGroup>
                  <Fab size="small" color="primary">
                    <AddIcon onClick={handleAdd} />
                  </Fab>
                  <CustomCKEditor
                    handleChange={(_event: any, content: any) =>
                      handleMcqQuestionChange(
                        content && content.getData(),
                        "hint",
                        index
                      )
                    }
                    label="Hint"
                    initialState={question?.hint}
                  />
                  <CustomCKEditor
                    handleChange={(_event: any, content: any) =>
                      handleMcqQuestionChange(
                        content && content.getData(),
                        "solution",
                        index
                      )
                    }
                    label="Solution"
                    initialState={question?.solution}
                  />
                </CardContent>
              </Card>
```

Comment: I tried to run your code snippet but I got some errors. Can you have a look?

Comment: I haven't provided full code to run here. It has various components and large code so I am not able to provide all the code here. I only provide some part of the code. If you want, I am happy to meet with you. Please share your meeting details. I will share the whole code.